# SQL script that runs other scripts in the same folder in a transaction

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have created a folder that has four scripts namely ScriptA.Sql, ScriptB.Sql, ScriptC.Sql.
The fourth one I want to create MasterScript.Sql that runs all the other scripts in a transaction. How do I accomplish this.

Any ideas and suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach is to make in a language other than SQL, such as PowerShell or C# or Python, which interacts well with both files and SQL Server.

However, if you really want to do it as a T-SQL script you can use xp_cmdshell and Osql to call the scripts.  Of course, this presumes that xp_cmdshell is enabled on your server, it is disabled by default and can open up security vulnerabilities if enabled.

Edit: Also, depending on your final purpose you could consider converting your scripts into stored procedures and stored procedures invoke each other quite readily in the normal way.

Comment: Well I am asking how to compile the scripts. The scripts that I mentioned Script A, B, C are stored procs. I want to create them on a new environment. So I need a script that compiles them. The reason I want it in a transaction is because if anything fails I can rollback.

Comment: So you mean the scripts A, B, C create stored procedures and you want to call them all in order to create the stored procedures on a new server?  Aside from making my edit inapplicable that doesn't change my answer.  I would create a Powershell script that opens a transaction, executes the others, and then commits.